# Interact with the GUI element into wpf editor

Tags: wpf, xaml

there is any way to interact with the GUI element into xaml designer (or blend)?

In other words, is possible open/close menu, open/close split button, navigate the gui element without run project?

Comment: As far as my knowledge is concern, answer is no

Comment: why does this question have a -1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but it's an hard work. You can find a good start point at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938(v=vs.90).aspx